# select users from database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rs=mysql_query("select user.userName,usertype.userType from user,usertype where user.userTypeId=usertype.userTypeId");
```

This query gets users with type, there is 2 type (user and admin). So I need to see only simple users not admin. How to fix it? Number 1 is admin type, number 2 is simple user.

Comment: Try to get a SQL query that works on the mysql console (or phpmyadmin) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your schema, this is near impossible to answer, but you're probably looking to do something like this:

```
select user.userName, usertype.userType
  from user, usertype
  where user.userTypeId = usertype.userTypeId
    and usertype.role = 'user'
```

Comment: @Simon you should accept this answer, check the tick next to it.